# How to solve this circular dependency issue?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have three classes : User, Account, and Model. User and Account are extending Model class.

User.js :

```
import Model from '@/classes/Model'
export default class User extends Model {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data)
  }
}
```

Account.js :

```
import Model from '@/classes/Model'
export default class Account extends Model {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data)
  }
}
```

And Model.js :

```
import Account from '@/classes/Account'
import User from '@/classes/User'

export default class Model {
  static _classesMapping = {
    Account,
    User
  }

  constructor(data) {
    ...
  }

  static create(models) {
    return new Model._classesMapping[this.name](models)
  }
}
```

I want to create Account and User instances from the static method create in Model like this : Account.create()

However, i get this error when compiling: "Super expression must either be null or a function" because of the circulary dependecy issue.
I don't know how i can solve this issue without having to passing the class as an argument to the Model.create method like this, which i find ugly

```
Account.create(data, Account)
```

Comment: Maybe remove all code from Model which relies on knowing the subclasses, and call methods implemented by the subclasses instead.

Comment: I will have many class that will extend the Model class, so implementing a 'create' method in each of them will be a bit boring. If I have to do that, i will, but if I can find a better solution, it would be good

Comment: Did you really mean `Account.create(data, Account)`? Or rather `Model.create(data, Account)`? Because in `Account.create(…)`, you can simply access `Account` as `this`. ...as you already realised because you're using `this.name`. Hm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create `Account` and `User` instances from the static method create in Model like this: `Account.create()`

Well, you don't need any `_classesMapping` for that. You can simply access the constructor by `this`, you don't need to go look it up by its name.

```
// Model.js:
export default class Model {
  constructor(data) {
    …
  }

  static create(models) {
    return new this(models)
  }
}
```

That solves your circular dependency problem by simply removing the dependency :-)

Comment: Damn ! Thanks you dude, I feel so dumb now .. It's working :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is to move your `classesMapping` to an external file.

So you get

- Model.js

  - User.js
  - Account.js
- ClassMapping.js

  - Which imports `User` and `Account` and is imported by Model.js

Comment: I alreay tried this, but the circulary dependency issue is always present because Model import ClassMaping and ClassMaping import Account and User. So it's equivalent to my first code unfortanely